# Update nested array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want do an updateMany() operation on a nested array for all documents of my collection.
Here is the documents format :

```
{
    "number": 1,
    "products": [{
        "name": "test",
        "compositions": ["water", "sugar"],
    }]
},
  {
    "number": 2,
    "products": [{
        "name": "test12",
        "compositions": ["cotton", "linen"],
    }]
}
```

How can add element ("color" for example) in **compositions** array nested in product array for all documents by doing updateMany() operation ?

I try this but it is not work :

```
db.getSiblingDB("mydatabase").getCollection("stock").find().forEach(element => {
  element.products.forEach(product => {
    db.stock.updateOne(
      {$set: {
         'compositions': { $addToSet: { 'product.compositions' :  "color"}}
     }})  
  })
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **all positional operator [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)** to update all elements in the array.

```
db.getSiblingDB("mydatabase").getCollection("stock").updateMany(
  {},
  { $addToSet: { "products.$[].compositions": "color" } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of if you don't want to update all elements, you can use `arrayFilters` (which allows you to use `$[i]` notation inside `option` section):
[mongodb example playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FP9IN0oBXaD)

```
db.getSiblingDB("mydatabase").getCollection("stock").updateMany(
  {},
  { $addToSet: { "products.$[i].compositions": "color" } },
  { arrayFilters: [{"i.name": "test12"}]
)
```